# Make custom kernels available to SageMaker Studio notebooks

Tags: amazon-web-services, conda, amazon-sagemaker

On starting the SageMaker Studio server, I can only see a set of predefined kernels when
I select kernel for any notebook.

[image: Predefined Kernels]

I create conda environments and persist them between sessions by pointing `.condarc` to a custom miniconda directory stored on EFS.

I want all notebooks to have access to environments stored in the custom miniconda directory. I can do that on the system terminal but can't seem to find a way to make the kernels available to notebooks.

I am aware of [Life Cycle Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebook-lifecycle-config.html) but that seems to be working only with notebooks instances rather than SageMaker Studio.

**Desired outcomes**

Ideally making custom kernels persistently available to notebooks but if that isn't feasible or requires custom docker image, I am happy with running a script manually every time I run the server.

**What I have tried so far:**

I ran the following which is a tweaked version of [start.sh](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/blob/master/scripts/persistent-conda-ebs/on-start.sh) meant to be for Life Cycle Configuration.

```html
#!/bin/bash

set -e

sudo -u sagemaker-user -i <<'EOF'
unset SUDO_UID
WORKING_DIR=/home/sagemaker-user/.SageMaker/custom-miniconda/
source "$WORKING_DIR/miniconda/bin/activate"
for env in $WORKING_DIR/miniconda/envs/*; do
    BASENAME=$(basename "$env")
    source activate "$BASENAME"
    python -m ipykernel install --user --name "$BASENAME" --display-name "$BASENAME"
done

EOF
```

That didn't work and I couldn't access the kernels from the notebooks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a persistent custom kernel in SageMaker studio, you can create an ECR repository and build a docker image with custom environment configurations. This image can then be attached to the SageMaker studio notebooks. [Reference link](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-custom-image-samples)!

SageMaker studio now also supports the use of lifecycle configurations. [Reference link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/customize-amazon-sagemaker-studio-using-lifecycle-configurations/)!